# How do I insert a row in excel and include the inserted row in a formula?

Tags: vba, excel

**Example:**

I have a cell "A1" that sums up some values in a row "IF"-something: =SUM.IF($C$5:$C$10;"Blue";$D$5:$D$10)

meaning: If columns C5 to C10 contains the word "Blue" in any row for example. "C7" and "C9", then the sum of "D7" and "D9" will be shown in "A1".

**My problem:**

If I insert a new row "5", then I want the formula to contain this row as well:
=SUM.IF($C$5:$C$11;"Blue";$D$5:$D$11)

**But what happens is that the formula is now:**

=SUM.IF($C$6:$C$11;"Blue";$D$6:$D$11)

So the formula contains only the original 5 rows "5-10" and now named "6-11".

**How do I make excel expand the formula to include the new row aswell so it sums up from "5-11"   =SUM.IF($C$5:$C$11;"Blue";$D$5:$D$11)?**

(I know I can make this work with a table, but this is a thought example and not my real situation. Actually I insert 5 rows at a time, and some cells are merged, so I can't convert the range of data into a table)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: there can be a VBA way to "automagically" adapt formula ranges. but if you're done with the accepted answer there's no need to waste time for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done. Set the row range reference in the formula to one row above you actual list, then everything should work.

For example, leave row 5 empty. Hide the row if you like. In cell A1, use the formula `=SUMIF($C$5:$C$10,"Blue",$D$5:$D$10)` (starting at row 5). Start entering values in row 6.

Now you can right-click Row 6 and *Insert* a new row, and the formula will continue to work as required.

Comment: Wow, that was really simple, but it worked, thanks a lot!